# How to find the closed form for this integral with complex-analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm working on this problem:[Looking for another way to calculate this integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581394/looking-for-another-way-to-calculate-this-integral)

And I come up an idea that notice:
    $$e^{ix} \cdot 2 \sin x = i (1-e^{2ix})$$
Hence
    $$\ln (2\sin x) + ix = \frac{i \pi}{2} + \ln (1-e^{2ix})$$
And we have 
    $$\ln ^{2} (2\sin x) - x^{2} = \Re \left [ \frac{i \pi}{2} + \ln (1-e^{2ix}) \right ] ^{2}$$
It suffices to find out the solution for this integral:
    $$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} x^{3} \left [ \frac{i \pi}{2} + \ln (1-e^{2ix}) \right ] ^{2} \text{d}x$$
The WA gives that it's about $-0.166961+0.2039i$

I substitute that $$z = e^{2ix}$$but I cannot work out the contour integral because it's a 1/3 circle centered at the original point and I don't know how to continue......

Would you please help me on this problem? Thanks in advance!